# How do I use transaction with oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I am trying to use transaction blocks on a SQL-Console with an Oracle DB. I'm used to use transaxction blocks in PostgreSQL like

```
BEGIN;
<simple sql statement>
END;
```

but in oracle it seems that this is not possible. I'm always getting "ORA-00900" errors and I don't know how to fix that. If I just use SQL-Statements like

```
<simple sql statement>
COMMIT;
```

it works. But isn't there some tag to define the start of a transaction? I tried

```
START TRANSACTION;
<simple sql statement>
COMMIT;
```

But it still throws an ORA-00900. My operating system is windows, I am using IntelliJ IDEA and a Oracle 11g DB.

Comment: You don't need to explicitely start a transaction, Oracle keeps track of that for you. You do, however, need to either commit or rollback the work you've done. and to execute a BEGIN-END; block, you need to enter the backslash on a new line. If you are still getting an ORA-00900 after that, then look to the syntax of your "simple sql statement" as Oracle syntax may be slightly different than you are used to also.

Answer (score 12):

You can have an implicit transaction block by issuing one SQL statement as in

```
<simple sql statement>
Commit;
```

For anonymous blocks or PL/SQL procedures/functions/packages more options are available that you may have seen in Postgres.

If you have several statements that must all succeed or all fall (an [atomic transaction](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Atomicity_(database_systems)) then, from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABGAAIG), you can do:

```
DECLARE
   <variable declaration>
BEGIN
   <simple sql statement>
   <simple sql statement>
   <simple sql statement>
   SAVEPOINT do_insert;
   <sql insert statement>
EXCEPTION
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      ROLLBACK TO do_insert;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Insert has been rolled back');
END;
--and commit outside the transaction
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal, read committed transaction, starts automatically with the first modified row.

If you want to set the transaction explicitly use:

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` - but the transaction will be physically created when first row is modified, not when this statement is executed.

or

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` - in this case read consistency will be as of this command is executed. `READ ONLY` transaction has the same read consistency effect.